# Extract Min Date from a string with several dates using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, extract, mindate

I am trying to extract the min date from a `varchar` string.

The data in the field looks like this

```
QTY DIFFERENCE - PO LINE 6.  147 ON PO / 192 ON INVOICE

5/18/2016 4:18:52 PM by ROOFING\ebuchanan
ANDREW SANTORI ISSUED THIS PO, PLEASE SEND TO HIS QUE

5/21/2016 9:48:42 AM by ROOFING\knaylor
RE-ROUTED TO ATS
```

Using this code

```
SELECT 
    UISeq,
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9/]%', Notes), 8000),
       PATINDEX('%[^0-9/]%', SUBSTRING(Notes, PATINDEX('%[0-9/]%', Notes), 8000) + 'X') -1) as 'MaxDate'
FROM 
    bAPUI
WHERE
    Notes IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    UISeq
```

I get this result from the record above

```
6
```

I also get

```
01/01/2000
```

On other fields

How do I correct the code to only return the Min date within each record field?

```
 UISeq  MinDate
  2      3
  3      5
 13   4/1/2016
 15      1
 17 
 18  4/15/2016
 19     3
 20  4/15/2016
 40  05/22/16
 43  05/22/16
 54  5/18/16
```

John's post is beyond my current ability

I have created the function, here is the code to extract the data

```
Declare @Str varchar(max);

Select @Str as Notes, Min(Key_Value)

from bAPUI, [dbo].[SA-udf-Str-Parse](replace(@Str,char(13),' '),' ')

Where Key_Value like '%/%'
  and len(Key_Value)>=10
```

What I am not understanding is how to get the bAPUI.Notes table/field into the select statement.

Comment: Good luck. This type of parsing on data that appears to be free text is borderline impossible. There just isn't anything concrete you can use to identify where a date begins or where it ends. You could probably isolate the dates but it would be challenging to extend that to include the time portion.

Comment: Is the sample you posted the contents of a single row? Or is that multiple rows? Providing some insight into your table will do you a LOT of good here.

Comment: Sean I am not worried about the time, just the date. Thanks

Comment: OK. Can you answer my question about the table structure?

Comment: It affected 825 rows

Comment: No. Is the sample data you posted a single row?

Comment: Yes see above. I also have the row named wrong it should be 'MinDate'

Comment: @Steve: a row doesn't have a "name" - are you talking about the **column**??

Comment: Yes Sorry, Marc the data needs to be returned in a single column, and it will have several rows. Very new to SQL.

Comment: Sean are you saying this is not possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses a string parser udf.  Perhaps in your data, or even just in the example, there were chr(13)'s, so I had to perform a replace(), there could be other extended characters that may need to be trapped.

```
Declare @Str varchar(max)
Set @Str='QTY DIFFERENCE - PO LINE 6.  147 ON PO / 192 ON INVOICE

5/18/2016 4:18:52 PM by ROOFING\ebuchanan
ANDREW SANTORI ISSUED THIS PO, PLEASE SEND TO HIS QUE

5/21/2016 9:48:42 AM by ROOFING\knaylor
RE-ROUTED TO ATS'

Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](replace(@Str,char(13),' '),' ')
Where Key_Value like '%/%'
  and len(Key_Value)>=10
```

Returns

```
Key_PS  Key_Value
13      5/18/2016
28      5/21/2016
```

While with a quick change

```
Select Min(Key_Value) from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](replace(@Str,char(13),' '),' ')
Where Key_Value like '%/%'
  and len(Key_Value)>=10
```

Returns

```
5/18/2016
```

There are millions of variations but here is mine.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('id26,id46|id658,id967','|')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL , Key_Value varchar(500))

As

Begin
   Declare @intPos int,@SubStr varchar(500)
   Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
   Set @String = Replace(@String,@delimeter+@delimeter,@delimeter)
   While @IntPos > 0
      Begin
         Set @SubStr = Substring(@String, 0, @IntPos)
         Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@SubStr)
         Set @String = Replace(@String, @SubStr + @delimeter, '')
         Set @IntPos = CharIndex(@delimeter, @String)
      End
   Insert into @ReturnTable (Key_Value) values (@String)
   Return 
End
```

So to apply to your data

```
Select UISeq,
      ,MinDate=(Select Min(Key_Value) from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](replace(Notes,char(13),' '),' ') Where Key_Value like '%/%' and len(Key_Value)>=10) 
FROM  bAPUI
WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
ORDER BYUISeq
```

I have no idea how this will perform on a large dataset

Comment: Unless you also provide your string splitter this is not a complete answer.

Comment: I would highly recommend you look into replacing that one. Using a loop for that is really slow. Here are several better options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Regardless you get a +1 from me.

Comment: Will take a peek.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: John I am getting this error message with the function 'Must declare the scalar variable "@IntPos"

Comment: Huh, I see the declare in the code provided.   1st line after the begin.  I don't understand why you would get an error

Comment: On another note, once you get the function running, you may want to tighten the where statement to avoid malformed dates

Comment: Case sensitive on your server?   Declare _int int;Set _INT = 1;Select _Int   returns 1   (replace the _ with @  -- would not let me post)

Comment: John I think I am going to need a bit more help with the select statement. I think I am really close. Thanks so much for your help so far. I posted the new select statement above

Comment: No worries.  I'm here and available.

Comment: Select UISeq,
      ,MinDate=(Select Min(Key_Value) from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](replace(Notes,char(13),' '),' ') Where Key_Value like '%/%' and len(Key_Value)>=10) 
FROM  bAPUI
WHERE Notes IS NOT NULL
ORDER BYUISeq

Comment: Sorry John but I am getting an error   -------- Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 14 String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: In the function Key_Value is set to varchar(500)  you could change this to varchar(max),   I suspect you have a string which exceeds 500 characters.   Make that change and let me know.

Comment: Try the query provide, but add TOP 10.  I just want make sure it is a data item.

Comment: Just to be safe, in the function set Key_Value varchar(max) and @Substr varchar(max)

Comment: That did the trick. But I discovered another problem. Some of the data is missing a space after the date. Any ideas?

5/3/20162:08:35PMbyROOFING\mroach
UPDATED

Comment: Let me see if I can tune it for a data pattern.   This is data people should rule the world.  We would not allow ugly data.

Comment: John not sure if this helps but it looks like everyone has a space in front of the date.---------POMAYHAVEBEENCLOSED
5/25/20169:32:13AMbyROOFING\dgallagher
PO#292387 ----------------
5/23/20168:26:05PMbyROOFING\ltalbot
289415
5/24/20168:12:20AMbyROOFING\gmack
NOTHINGFORPICKUPCHARGEOF$75.00
5/24/20168:58:21PMbyROOFING\ltalbot
UPDATED289415

Comment: How many years does your data span.   In other words what would be the min/max year one would find in the notes?

Comment: Just started with this database so >=2016

Answer (score 0):

Super quick draft - Use CHARINDEX And LEFT to retrieve all characters up to the first space, then convert that text to a DATE, then use MIN to select the EARLIEST date.

[image]

`select @str as string
,left(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',@str)) -- Get the position of the first space, then select all characters up to the space
,MIN(convert(date,left(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',@str)))) -- Convert the selected characters to a date and then use MIN to select earliest date`

Comment: My answer may be completely wrong if the date could be ANYWHERE in the string - I thought the string started with the date

Comment: received this error "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"